# external js delay affecting my function execution

Tags: javascript

Its seems like in our application javascript function execution or ajax request waiting till external js loaded.

In Details, we are using some external script in our app like for chat, tag manager etc. when external scripts are down, it's affecting my other ajax request, seems like it's executing only after getting a timeout from the pending scripts. mostly its affected for dynamically appending elements. I would like to get a solution like send only the external request after every other function executed or any other suggestion.

Comment: if the external script has no dependencies you can try loading it asynchronously via async attribute over script tag. If it does have a dependency you will need to reconsider your app architecture and use modular approach with module loaders like requirejs, systemjs, webpack etc

Comment: I have tried this method, unfortunately no luck

Comment: we will need more info about your app architecture. Are you using pure javascript ? From your problem description i guess you will need to go with some modular approach.Also does that external file have any dependencies with your application ?

Comment: We are using jquery without any modular approach. Unfortunately, I am afraid to make a restructuring, because it's a running app.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go around this is to use the **async** parameter when loading your js files.
This does not stop your page from doing other things, it asynchronously loads the JS files.
**REMEMBER**

You should never use this approach if your functionality is dependant on those js files or you should call those functionalities from within those JS files.

The syntax for asynchronous calling of JS files is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" async></script>
```

Read more about async at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp